# is that true by saying "all stuff with `Self` is a generic some kind of" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

already known that protocol with a `Self` in its declaration is a generic protocol, example given below, which Self will resolve to adopting type

```
protocol Ordered {
    func precedes(other: Self) -> Bool
}
```

now coming with a func like this, the `Self` here will also resolve accordingly, which give this func a generic trait

```
extension Comparable {
    func precedes(other: Self) -> Bool { return self < other }
}
```

So, in short, can we say "all stuff with `Self` is a generic some kind of"